# Need help with wiring to thermostat and condensate pump

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire, condensate

I've searched a lot and can't quite find what how to solve this one. I installed an ecobee smart thermostat, which didn't work with 5 wire connection so I switched to their PEK module with only 4 wires. With this wiring the heat is working fine, but the cooling doesn't (the compressor doesn't kick in, and the fan is blowing ambient air). Anyhow, I tried to map my wiring and this is what I have. Looks wired to me that the Rc is jumped with the common. Any ideas how to fix it? [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What make/model air handler and furnace do you have? Why is the condensate pump hooked to the thermostat? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The model is Trane XB. The condensate pump connection is for a safety switch, so in case of a flood it shuts down the AC completely through the 24v red wire (low voltage).

Comment: Is there a C wire between the AHU and the condensate pump?

Comment: No, there is one between the outside unit and the AHU. For some reason, the C from the thermostat is connected to the R that goes from the thermostat to the pump. I think i need to break this connection and connect the two C's on the thermostat and AHU. Makes sense?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen a condensate pump hooked up to the RC wire this looks wrong , the pump should have a level or float sensor and should function with the air handler not running or the thermostat not calling for cooling. The reason I say this is after a cooling cycle in some cases their will be a large amount of water dripping from the evaporator coil so the condensate pump is not normally even connected to the thermostat. I would verify that the yellow is going high when the call for cooling is on.

Comment: Agree.  The pump should have constant power. The float is the on/off switch.

Answer (score 1):

On the hot (120V) side, yes, the pump should always have power available, hence it is plugged into a receptacle.  But this inquiry is pertaining to the cold (24V) side which in the case of condensate pumps (either for HE Condensing Burn Assemblies or AC Evap Coils), the cold side provides property and equipment protection from overflowing condensate causing damage by opening the call for service (R wire if condensing furnace and AC or Y wire if no condensing furnace) 24V circuit between the equipment and the t-stat.  To answer the question, remove the C wire from the R/RC wire, and it must run to the C terminal on the air handler board.  Many condensate pump manufactures confuse people, experienced people(myself included), by infusing the word "common" on a over-simplistic attempt at a wiring schematic by the overflow swith blade terminals.  Keep it simple, depending on if you produce condensate during both heating and cooling operations or just cooling, determines how to wire the low volt side.